# How can I load background tiles in Leaflet Web Gis?

Tags: leaflet

I have leaflet code in a web Gis Django APP as shown:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Layers Control Tutorial - Leaflet</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
 
 var L1  = L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L1B  = L.tileLayer('http://127.0.0.1:8000/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L2   = L.tileLayer('http://tiles.wmflabs.org/hillshading/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
   L2B   = L.tileLayer('http://127.0.0.1:8000/gray/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L3  = L.tileLayer('https://tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L3B  = L.tileLayer('http://127.0.0.1:8000/hikebike/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L4 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L4B = L.tileLayer('htt://127.0.0.1:8000/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
  L5 = L.tileLayer('http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg');
  L5B = L.tileLayer('htt://127.0.0.1:8000/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg');

 var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [39.73, -104.99],
  zoom: 10,
  layers: [L1]
 });

 var baseLayers = {
  "L1": L1,"L2": L2,'L3':L3,'L4':L4,
 };

 var overlays = {'L5':L5,
  };

 L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

L1:  `L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')` load tile layer for user and L1B:`L.tileLayer('http://127.0.0.1:8000/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')` send to my server that which tiles have seen by user?

I want when I select any layer (just one click)  like select L1 (on control layer) same time enable L1 and L1B (in background), and when  click L2(on control layer)   same time enable L2  and L2B (in background), and ... .

I don't want add L1B or any B layer to control layer Because I have so many Layer and control layer The  face becomes ugly and It will be confusing.

How can I do?

Comment: Use `L.LayerGroup`s.

Comment: Please submit your answer for select best solution.